# Default argument of parent class not changing in child class python

Tags: python, class, object, arguments, default

Here is sample code
[image]

If I create parent class Shape then the value of self.height is 29, but in case of child class is is showing 0(which is default argument of parent class).

Why this is happening? and how can I assign values in child class in that case?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

In your definition of Triangle class, you are calling Shape's initializer with a whole new set of values in this case. A working Triangle class definition may look a little bit like this:

```py
class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, name='Default', height=0, base=0):
        Shape.__init__(self, name, height, base)
    #   Or
    #   super().__init__(name, height, base)
```

In this form of the Triangle definition when we calling Shape's **init** method, i did not pass extra value to the Shape's initializer as it is not needed. Value assigning is already done in Triangle's **init** arguments and those values simply passed to the super class' (Shape's) initializer.

Comment: Thank you I got it, 
One thing is that I must have to  pass the self parameter in  Shape.__init__()

Comment: @Shourov edited my answer according to your comment. Thanks for the correction!